# Xdebug boosts site speed

Tags: apache, wamp, prestashop, xdebug

I have WAMP stack for development and a lot of sites are going slow, but I have a really big issue with PrestaShop because loading time is 1 min on average.

Although the content is loaded, the main request is responding very slowly and Chrome's waterfall shows that the delay is caused by Content Downloading, but all assets are already downloaded (local storage) or cached.

I noticed that when I enable the xdebug listener (on VSCode) the site is responding as it should, i.e. within miliseconds.

Any idea what might be happening ?

[image: xdebug enable]

[image: xdebug disabled]

Comment: xdebug is a debugging tool to be used for development.  You are not using xdebug on your production server installation are you?

Comment: nope,  neither an AMP stack is appropriate for prod :)